# UIwebview: Know where the user is in the webcontent

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Suppose I wish to load a UIWebview with a webpage that contains content(similar to that in a book) in the form of different chapters (say chapter 1,2,3,4) and I want to place a favorite chapter functionality.

My question is ,if on the UIWebview, the user is scrolling between chapters, how would I know where the user is finally , so that I can mark the chapter as favorite.?

Is there a way to know what the content is at content offset of webview's scrollview ?

Answer (score 0):

implement [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidStartLoad:) and define your object as web view  delegate . define this method, which will inform you whenever you load the page from url. you can book save it then load the webview with this url later to bring the user next time directly to this page.

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
         NSLog(@"can load this URL :%@",request.URL.absoluteString);

         //return FALSE; //to stop loading
         return YES;
    }

   - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
      NSLog(@"starts to load URL :%@",webView.request.URL.absoluteString);
   }


   - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
      NSLog(@"Loaded URL :%@",webView.request.URL.absoluteString);
   }
```

Comment: I am loading all the chapters once and going to a particular chapter say chapter 5. Now I scroll to any chapter say chapter 10, I am not loading any url. so how can I know if the user is at what chapter?